# Add endpoint to existing FastAPI server

Tags: python, routes, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a function that gets API endpoint and a function to serve on this endpoint:

```
from api.server.create_new_game import create_new_game

app = FastAPI()

def handle_get_endpoints(app, endpoint, function):
    @app.get(endpoint)
    async def handle_endpoint():
        return function()

handle_get_endpoints(app, "/api/create_game", create_new_game)
uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Now, the function `create_new_game` (which is located on another file) should generate a new endpoint with unique UUID for the game, then serve the new endpoint.

How can I create a function like that -- that is being called from existing server's API and then adding a new API endpoint to this server and refreshes it?

Hope it was clear enough.

Comment: I don't think you actually want to do that. I think you can want some endpoint like `/api/game/<id>/...`. You generate a unique id, and you use this in subsequent requests.

Comment: @larsks I didn't fully understand you. You mean that I should attach the id as an variables in the URL and not to serve it on seperate path?

Comment: Right. By using the id as a variable in a path, it **is** a separate path for each game, but you don't need to register a new route whenever you create a game.

Comment: @larsks. Got it, actually a really good solution, thanks! I only have one issue with it, if I'm using your method I don't have direct access to a game. In my method I thought that I will export a python object that will represent the game and the function will modify it as the game continues, in your way I cannot do that

Comment: I disagree with your reasoning there; I don't think this solution has any impact on whether or not you have "direct access" to your game. It's your code; you decide how to store and access application state. That's not dictated by the paths used by remote clients.

Comment: @larsks. got what you say, you're right. Thank you very much for the help!